# Will Late or Will come Late?

Tags: verbs, adjectives

In our daily stand-up calls, my Project manager says "Ajay will be late today". I am just wondering like he will not late anymore!!, He will just come late or He is running late today from the regular schedule.

Its little bit confusing, which one of the following is the correct one?

1. Ajay will be late
2. Ajay will come late

Hope to get a clear idea.

Comment: I can't find the question in your question?  Both of the options you supply work.  What is it you are trying determine?

Comment: Hi @EllieK, I would like to know which one is accurate #1 or #2 ?

Comment: Both are fine and mean the same thing, "Ajay will arrive late," meaning Ajay will not arrive at the time we had expected him to arrive.  After his expected arrival time has passed you might say, "Ajay is late."

Comment: After his expected arrival time has passed you might say, "Ajay is late." -- This clears my doubt. Thanks. How to do upvote the comment :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are fine and mean the same thing, "Ajay will arrive late," meaning Ajay will not arrive at the time we had expected him to arrive. After his expected arrival time has passed you might say, "Ajay is late."